# Traversing an object hirerarchy

Tags: java, reflection

I'm looking for ways to traverse an arbitrary object hierarchy in Java. Obviously, using the reflection API directly is one option but what libraries are built on top of it that could make the task easier?

Specifically I want to grab all the objects referenced directly or indirectly from a base object that implement a given interface. The hierarchy can contain loops, although the objects I'm looking for will form a DAG, so ideally I'd want them to be returned in topological order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you look at Apache BeanUtils yet? -> http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

I don't know if they cover everything you need but it's quite good and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion. If you have your objects implement the `MyObject` interface, the following will traverse and extract all components to a `map`.

```
public interface MyObject{
      String getName();
      void addChild(MyObject obj);
      MyObject[] getChildren();
}   

// This will visit and extract all children
public void visitMyObject(MyObject cmp, Map hashMap){
      // Add this component
      if(cmp != null) hashMap.put(cmp.getName(), cmp);
      // Go visit all children
      for(MyObject subComponent : cmp.getChildren()){
          visitMyObject(subComponent, hashMap);
      }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the object hierarchy is a lot more complex and there could be a number of unknown (at compile time that is) objects in it, which could still reference stuff that I'm interested in.